# Ident authentication failed error when connecting to PostgreSQL via PgAdmin III

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to connect to my postgres server instance using PgAdmin III from the same machine the instance is on, but I keep getting the "Ident authentication failed" error when trying to connect. Here the steps I formed performed to try to achieve connectivity:

I created a new user in Postgres called 'pguser1':
[user pguser1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EB1z.png)

I modified my pg_hba.conf file in order to use md5 authentication:
[pg_hba.conf with md5 auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3G71.png)

I then tried to connect via pgAdminIII, but I've had no success.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently I need a reputation score of 10 to post > 2 links. Here's a screenshot of the error I'm getting: http://i.imgur.com/kWYjdmG.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you create a **md5** password for the user or update the user?

If not this may help

```
U=pguser1; P=yourpassword; echo -n md5; echo -n $P$U | md5sum | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Which produces an md5 password. md575a63f65a68540d053ec41f410d9ab24

So the next step would be to update/create the user password .

```
CREATE USER theuser PASSWORD 'md575a63f65a68540d053ec41f410d9ab24';
```

OR

```
ALTER USER postgres password 'md575a63f65a68540d053ec41f410d9ab24';
```

You could then login with (in this case)

```
user pguser1 Password: yourpassword
```

All the best

Comment: Great news @jack_bauer Enjoy. Postgres really is a beauty