# Cannot connect to Postgres using Tableau

Tags: postgresql, tableau-api

**Setup:**

1. Tableau 9.0.3
2. Postgres 9.5.  (default installation)
3. Installed the psqlodbc drivers cited at:  https://www.tableau.com/en-us/support/drivers?edition=pro&lang=en-us&platform=windows&cpu=64&version=9.0&__full-version=9000.15.0615.1857#postgres
4. All of this installed on windows 7 box

[image]

**Login:**

Server: Localhost

Port: 5432

Database: mds_experiment

Username: postgres

Password:

But I'm unable to login!
[image]

This doesn't make sense to me.  These are the settings I use to connect to a psql shell, for example:

[image]

The pgAdmin3 console seems to confirm that there is no password for the postgres user (by default there shouldn't be, and I've logged in elsewhere without a password.

[image]

I looked through the PgAdmin server log:

[image]

The logs show failing due to some incorrect password authentication/response.

one further clue:

If I try to connect to a non-existent database, tableau throws the same error, and i see the same sorts of errors in the PgAdmin server log.

[image]

Comment: I noticed you're using dropbox in your path. Have you tried not using a cloud storage location for your directory? I've had issues before running scripts that write to files in my dropbox sync folder. Maybe that could help.

Comment: Hi I've just answered a similar question. Ref md5 passwords here -> Ident authentication failed error when connecting to PostgreSQL ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36973881/ident-authentication-failed-error-when-connecting-to-postgresql-via-pgadmin-iii/36985757#36985757